# Using Effort (EF Testing Tool) with Computed Column

Tags: database, entity-framework, c#-4.0, integration-testing, effort

I have a number of integration tests which access the DB directly - create test prerequisite objects - performs the tests and then cleans up afterwards - however I wonted to try out the same approach in-memory.

I have just used *[Effort](http://effort.codeplex.com/)* in my project and it works very easily. However I've hit a problem that I have been trying - but unable to solve.

One of the tables that I need filled up with dummy data - as a test prerequisite - contains a computed column (nvarchar, not null). For the scope of the test I really don't care about that column's value - but even if I try to insert dummy data, my data is ignored and then I get hit with an error:

```
"Column 'x' cannot be null. Error code: GenericError"
```

In my tests I am using the same edmx file as is used by the actual code. This prevents me from constantly updating the edmx copy.

Is there a way in which I can force the test to update the edmx (at runtime) so that column is a nullable non-computed column? [overriding OnModelCreating] or is there way to insert a default value (anything goes for this column) to stop this error? [overriding SaveChanges]

I have currently tried the following:

- Attaching the objects using .Attach() instead of .Add()
- Setting the EntityState to Unchanged after adding
- Forcing the value through Entry.OriginalValues [this values since entity is in Added state]

**Edit:**

I have tried overriding the *OnModelCreating* method, but to no avail since this is DB-First.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity_Name>().Property(p => p.x).IsOptional().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your EDMX file in XML editor, find your entity under the StorageModels,
and add to the column definition  `StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed"`.

But if you update or delete and add that table you will loose this modification. Actually you can write console app that will update you edmx file and add  `StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed"` where needed and you can add those app to prebuild events in studio.

Comment: I don't think you get the question.The model is already set to computed. I want the reverse affect - but ONLY for testing. So I cannot remove the 'Computed' field in the actual EDMX.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the problem was a bug in the Effort database. When the computed column is based on non-nullable columns, the computed column would also automatically become non-nullable. Therefor, the Effort database was expecting a non-null value. With the latest update the problem is resolved. You have to set the global `EntityFrameworkEffortManager.UseDefaultForNotNullable` flag as true.

See the [issue on github](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Effort/issues/62#issuecomment-471199839)