# unit testing with effort for entity framework 6 with computed values

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, effort

Using effort EF6 with code first does not populate computed values. I have a datetime field (FechaCreacion) that is computed. How can I emulate it in Effort, so It is populated with DateTime.Now after savingChanges() ?

This post [Using Effort (EF Testing Tool) with Computed Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232210/using-effort-ef-testing-tool-with-computed-column) is DB First instead of Code First as my example, but seems unanswered too.

```
EffortConnection connection = (EffortConnection)DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();

using (var c = new ControlConfigContext(connection))
{
    c.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

    CambioRepositoryTestLoadData.Load(c);

    string direccionMac = "FFFF";
    var repo = new CambioRepository(c);
    var primerConcesionarioTerminal = repo.GetPrimerConcesionarioTerminal(direccionMac);


    Assert.AreEqual("terminal1", primerConcesionarioTerminal.Terminal);
}
```

This value is computed in SQLServer as GetDate()

```
this.Property(t => t.FechaCreacion).HasColumnName("FechaCreacion").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

In sql server works well, but when using Effort in unit testing, the field gets empty date value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This would seem like an issue with Effort.  I have opened an issue on their github site: https://github.com/tamasflamich/effort/issues/62

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed with the latest update.

You have to set the global `EntityFrameworkEffortManager.UseDefaultForNotNullable` flag as true.